# How should I relate users to domain objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-roles

I'd like to use the built in ASP.NET membership and role providers to create a system that restricts what each authenticated user can view and edit.

The software already has the concepts of "Items" and "Groups". Each Item belongs in a Group.

The users of the system, in reality, belong to the same Groups.  This is currently not expressed in my domain model.

There are two levels of privileges I would like to extend to these users, View and Edit.  If they are in a Group, I would like them to be able to view the Items in that Group. If they have Edit privileges on that Group, I would like them to be able to Edit that Group's items.

Users typically belong to 1 Group, but may at some point belong to multiple. It's possible a user may have View privileges on multiple Groups, but Edit privileges on only 1 (or some) of the Groups they can view.

I'm not sure how to tackle this.  Should I simply create 2 roles (using the asp.net role provider) for every group, i.e., Group1View, Group1Edit and so on?  Or should I create another table that creates a relationship between the aspnet_Users table and the Groups table, with a third column identifying their privilege level?

Eventually I would like to implement Privilege checks somewhat similar to what Steve Smith blogged about here: http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/favor-privileges-over-role-checks/

Thanks for any input you may have to offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a custom Membership and Role provider to implement this, and wrap this security component you are referring to.  I would only use the Membership and Role provides only to serve the minimal requests that you need, and not depend on it for your entire application security.

The Role provider won't suite your needs well for a custom security with a hierarchical complexity.  What you mentioned would work (with the names), and a custom role provider could derive the names of the roles the user has access too from the components you mentioned.  However, I would only use that to handle built-in framework functionality (login controls, site map controls, or whatever you use), and for everything else use your own security setup.

Roles provider will end up being too restrictive for your needs in the long run.

HTH.